# c++ curl ssl certificate include

Tags: c++, ssl, curl

Recently I've been working on an application that gathers some info from an secure server. The problem is that, if I want to give to someone else the app, they need to have the CAcert/privkey.I couldn't find any libraries that I can use to include CAcert/privkey inside the project.Any ideas?

```
std::string do_request( std::string type, std::string post_data ) {
        CURL* c_url = curl_easy_init( );

        if ( !c_url )
            return _( "null" );

        std::string to_return;

        curl_easy_setopt( c_url, CURLOPT_URL, std::string( api_endpoint + type + post_data ).c_str( ) );
        curl_easy_setopt( c_url, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, user_agent.c_str( ) );
        curl_easy_setopt( c_url, CURLOPT_NOPROXY, api_endpoint );

        curl_easy_setopt( c_url, CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE, _( "PEM" ) );
        curl_easy_setopt( c_url, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, _( "path\\key.pem" ) );
        curl_easy_setopt( c_url, CURLOPT_CAINFO, _( "path\\ca.pem" ) );

        curl_easy_setopt( c_url, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1L );
        curl_easy_setopt( c_url, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1L );

        curl_easy_setopt( c_url, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback );
        curl_easy_setopt( c_url, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &to_return );

        auto code = curl_easy_perform( c_url );

        return to_return;
    }
```

Comment: You speak of `CAcert/privkey` but code says `path\\key.pem`.  You don't usually have the private key for the CA, so you are trying to setup a client side certificate (key and cert)?  The pem file is just text, you could store it in your source code as a variable and write out a temporary file.  You upload the files somewhere, and download them.

Comment: There is BLOB api in CURLOPT to load data from memory instead of file: [CURLOPT_SSLKEY_BLOB](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLKEY_BLOB.html), [CURLOPT_CAINFO_BLOB](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CAINFO_BLOB.html). How to store the key/certificates in memory is up to you: you can encode them as base64 string and store in global string variable or directly as binary array or additionally encrypt it somehow and so on.